# For Each loop dont stop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I have an Excel code written in VBA. I want to find phrase WJ in Column and select the appropriate values from it. I do this with `For Each` loop but loop doesn't stop after searching all WJ phrases.

```
Sub Calc()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Loc As Range
    Dim Phrase As String
    Dim OnlyNumber As String
    Dim Weight As String
    Dim Price As String
    Dim WeightPrice As String
    Dim WjSum As String

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Sh.UsedRange
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:=" WJ ")
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            Do Until Loc Is Nothing
                Phrase = Split(Loc.Value, ".21 ")(1)
                OnlyNumber = Left(Phrase, Len(Phrase) - 4)
                Price = Split(OnlyNumber, " ")(1)
                Weight = Split(OnlyNumber, " ")(0)`
                
                If Weight > 0 And Weight <= 10 Then
                    WeightPrice = 8
                ElseIf Weight > 10 And Weight <= 20 Then
                    WeightPrice = 12
                ElseIf Weight > 20 And Weight <= 40 Then
                    WeightPrice = 16
                ElseIf Weight > 40 And Weight <= 60 Then
                    WeightPrice = 18
                ElseIf Weight > 60 And Weight <= 80 Then
                    WeightPrice = 20
                ElseIf Weight > 80 And Weight <= 100 Then
                    WeightPrice = 25
                ElseIf Weight > 100 And Weight <= 300 Then
                    WeightPrice = 30
                ElseIf Weight > 300 Then
                    WeightPrice = 100
                End If
                
                WjSum = Weight + Price
                
                Range("D93").Value = WjSum
                
                Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
            Loop
        End If
    End With
    Set Loc = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not your `For Each` that never stops but your `Do`-Loop. `.FindNext` will find the next match but restarts at the top if not more values found - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext. You need to remember the address of your first match and check if the next match is different than your first match.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simplified code snippet

```
Sub FindAllInUsedRange()
    Dim usedRange As Range
    Set usedRange = ActiveSheet.usedRange
    Debug.Print usedRange.Address
    
    Dim firstFoundAddress As String
    Dim foundRange As Range
    Set foundRange = usedRange.Find("a")
    firstFoundAddress = foundRange.Address

    Do
        'Do something useful with foundRange
        Debug.Print foundRange.Address
        Set foundRange = usedRange.FindNext(foundRange)
    Loop While foundRange.Address <> firstFoundAddress

End Sub
```

EDIT

Source excel table

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a |  |
| 2 | b |  |
| 3 | a |  |
| 4 | b |  |
| 5 | a |  |
| 6 | b |  |

produces following result in Immediate window

$A$1:$A$6

$A$3

$A$5

$A$1

Comment: it doesn't work. This only search fist value and stop i need to find all phrase in column. Please help

Comment: I test it again and everything works well for me.